# Why can't I find Alternate CSS

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, css, style.css

I am looking for "Alternate Css" but I can't seem to find it in the "Master Page Setting" and I can't see the "Site Collection Feature" because I need to activate the features with 'publishing' in it.

Thanks

Comment: how about going to `https://sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx` directly and changing it there ?

Comment: what version of sharepoint you using?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you want to use SharePoint Designer to access site collection feature and find Alternate CSS?

If that’s the case, we are not able to enable features though SharePoint Designer.

I recommend you enable publishing feature through SharePoint UI which goes to site settings->site collection features and manage site features.
Or use [PowerShell command](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/03/activate-publishing-feature-using-powershell-in-sharepoint.html).

To find Alternate CSS URL, go to site settings->Look and Feel->Master Page.

Answer (score 1):

Site collection features are available under Site Collection Administrator section.

Make sure you are site collection admin.